# convert multi-dimensional associated array to be indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have multi-multidimensional array result with many arrays inside ( associative arrays) and i want to replace the inside arrays to be indexed arrays
the original array result like this :

```
Data Saved: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => john
            [ServiceDescAR] => description
            [user_id] => 13
            [pos] => 29.958040,30.915489
            [icon] => http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png
            [distance] => 0.00460411726624673
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => angel
            [ServiceDescAR] => description
            [user_id] => 11
            [pos] => 29.958042,30.915478
            [icon] => http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png
            [distance] => 0.005705603509640217
        )

)
```

and i want to replace all keys to be indexed, it will be like this
how to do that

```
Data Saved: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => john
            [2] => description 
            [3] => 13
            [4] => 29.958040,30.915489
            [5] => http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png
            [6] => 0.00460411726624673
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => angel
            [2] => description 
            [3] => 11
            [4] => 29.958042,30.915478
            [5] => http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png
            [6] => 0.005705603509640217
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_values` to extract all values from array (without the keys):

```
$result = array_map('array_values', $inputArray);
```

The resulting inner arrays indices will be zero-based.

Comment: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Use of undefined constant array_values - assumed 'array_values'</p>

Comment: $result = array_map('array_values', $inputArray);

Comment: @user1080247 Sorry, forgot that! Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: can i do this without array_map

Comment: why would you do that? but of course you can, you can create an empty array `$result = []` and loop thru your `$inputArray` using `foreach` and calling `array_values` for every inner value.

Comment: because i want to change the value for the key number 3 to be a link

Comment: like this <a href= "http::/www.site.com/id=11"></a>